# playing mp3 with jquery jplayer plugin

Tags: jquery, jplayer

i m trying to play a file using [jplayer](http://www.jplayer.org/)

the site i have experimented is:-

http://122.176.89.242/band

the background music is played on chrome

but not in firefox

how can i play on firefox

thanks

Answer (score 4):

It probably doesn't work in Firefox because of the lack of native MP3 support. Adding an [Ogg Vorbis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorbis) version of your music (which you seem to have commented out in your source code) should solve the problem.

See [this demo](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-01/) and look at the source. It works in Firefox:

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            m4a: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/m4a/Miaow-07-Bubble.m4a",
            oga: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-07-Bubble.ogg"
        }).jPlayer("play");
    },
    ended: function (event) {
        $(this).jPlayer("play");
    },
    swfPath: "../js",
    supplied: "m4a, oga"
});
```

By the way, who is this classy band-cum-DJ whose experienced hands would make my party different and wonderfully memorable?